# Как открыть Excel файл в памяти и читать листы в цикле, не переоткрывая файл на каждой итерации в цикле?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, оптимизация, производительность

Есть задача, в цикле `for` собирать данные с листов определенных столбцов (одинаковых) Excel файла, но возникла проблема на больших файлах. Если файл "тяжёлый" то открытие файла и чтение данных с определенного листа на каждой итерации цикла занимает примерно 30 секунд. Это слишком много, и я решил открыть файл в памяти через `open` и обращаться как бы к открытому файлу в памяти. На тяжелый файлах это дало прирост скорости:

- обработка вкладок без open - 299 сек
- обработка вкладок с open - 267 сек

Вопрос, правильно ли я обращаюсь к открытому файлу в памяти через `open`?

Я ожидал прирост в скорости обработки хотя бы в 2 раза. Как я был наивен.

```
file_excel_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=path.dirname(__file__),
                                                 filetypes=(("Excel 2007", "*.xlsx"),
                                                            ("Excel 97", "*.xls"),
                                                            ("all files", "*.*")))
excel_in_memory = open(file_excel_path, 'rb')

for i in list_active_sheets:
     df = pd.read_excel(excel_in_memory,
                        sheet_name=i,
                        usecols=(3,11),
                        encoding='utf8')
     print(df)

excel_in_memory.close()
```

Comment: Сформулировал по основному вопросу

Comment: `excel_in_memory = open(file_excel_path, 'rb')` -- тут еще не считывания в память, для считывания нужно вызвать `read`: `excel_in_memory = open(file_excel_path, 'rb').read()`, тогда в `excel_in_memory` будет весь файл (в байтах)

Comment: Не помогает. Файл загружается, растет размер потребляемой памяти на размер файла, после входа программы в указанный цикл вижу как память растёт в реальном времени по 1-2 мб в секунду, при обработке каждого листа. 
30мб программа
+ 40 мб после загрузки файла = 70мб
+ 1-2 мб в сек при чтении листа в цикле = 120 мб
- 40мб = 70 мб

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [pandas.ExcelFile.parse](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelFile.parse.html):

```
ef = pd.ExcelFile(filename)
for sheet_name in ef.sheet_names:
    df = ef.parse(sheet_name=sheet_name, usecols=[3, 11], encoding='utf8')
    ...
```

PS также стоит сравнить скорость работы `pd.ExcelFile()` и `ef.parse()`  для раличных Excel движков, указав параметр `pd.ExcelFile(filename, engine="...")`.

Поддерживаемые движки: `None`, `xlrd`, `openpyxl`, `pyxlsb`